# Disappearing variables while restructuring with casestovars

Tags: syntax, spss

When I run CASESTOVARS syntax or even use the "restructure" wizard in SPSS to make my long database wide, it seems to be dropping certain variables. So for example, I have 7 visit days for 10 exam areas. I have record ids for each person in the database and the index id is a variable with the visit day # in it.

When I run the restructure command, new variables for each exam area up to 7 visit appear, as expected, except for two exam areas. There only appears the original variable and rest of visit day data is missing.

Also, I thought it was a format issue, and i have reformated all data to be idential, both string or numeric or scale and it keeps coming up with same problem.

Here is syntax I have used:

```
CASESTOVARS 
/ID=record_id 
/INDEX=VisitDay 
/GROUPBY=INDEX
/separator = "_"
/AUTOFIX =YES.

record_id  VisitDay   Site1  Site1nodule  Site2   Site2nodules
1001    Base        1   0       0   0
1001    VisitMo3    1   0       0   0
1001    VisitMo6    1   0       0   0
1002    Base        1   0       0   0
1002    VisitMo3    1   0       0   0
1002    VisitMo6    1   0       0   0
1003    Base            1   0       0   0
1003    VisitMo3    1   0       0   0
1003    VisitMo6    1   0       0   0
```

I get missing variables...in this case I will get back only Site 1 and no Site 1_Base,  Site 1_VisitMo3, Site 1_VisitMo6 - even though I will get it all correct for Site 2 and others, for example.

Also occasionally when i have been trying different methods, I have been getting an error "sets from the original data will still be in used in the restructured data. I should use the "Use sets" dialogue" I can't find any information to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

`Casestovars` checks for each variable, before expanding it, if it is actually "fixed" (has a fixed value for all index values per ID) or not. If it is, by default, it doesn't get expanded. The default can be changed:  instead of `/autofix=yes`, just use

```
/autofix=no
```

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by Fixed value for all index values?  Do you mean the length and type are the same? Also, i tried this code with autofix=no and it didn't work, either.

Comment: In fact, it corrupts my entire database when I run it with "NO".

Comment: I've tried the code with `/autofix=no` on your example data and it worked fine - maybe there is another problem in the data that isn't expressed in the example. You can edit your original question, show your code using `/autofix=no` and describe what happened when you used it. Also try to give a more representative example of the data. For a fuller explanation for the `fix` and `autofix` look [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21484860)

Comment: I am working with a large dataset - it seems to be an issue with some, but not all variables. I have tried reformatting the variables, etc and nothing is working. I have also tried making smaller subdatasets and with the variables in question, again, when i run casetovars on them, it doesn't work. It is very frustrating issue to have!

Comment: Please edit your post with an example of data that *doesn't* work with `/autofix=no` so I can try to find the problem